# Compare arraySize with integer

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am trying to comparer ArrayList size with integer value but it returns false.

```
<c:if test="${langages.size()>2}">
  //code
</c:if>
```

When I `${langages.size}` it gives me value 4. What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%
   List<String> language = new ArrayList();
   language.add("English");
   language.add("French");
   language.add("Spanish");
   pageContext.setAttribute("language", language);
%>
<c:if test="${fn:length(language) > 2}">
     list length is greater than 2
</c:if>    
${language}
```

By the way, the code you posted does work for my version of JSTL(1.2.1). Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `gt` E.g.

```
<c:if test="${langages.size() gt 2}">
        <h1> aaa</h1>
</c:if>
```